# Query for the most fresh data

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a mongoose model like this:

```
source: { type: String, required: true }, //This is either A, B, C or D
title: { type: String, required: true },
link: { type: String, required: true },
date: { type: Number, required: true } //Unix Timestamp
```

Is it possible to get a list of the latest record for each of the `source` (A,B,C,D) based on the `date`(unix timestamp)?
Basically the latest, freshest data for each source.
Thanks

Comment: Please show what you have tried and how it did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation top perform this.

First [$sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) your data by date descendant, then [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) by source,
keeping only the [$first](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) document in your accumulator,  and finally do
a [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) to reshape your data as original.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $sort: {
      date: -1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$source",
      data: {
        $first: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$data"
    }
  }
])
```

[You can test it here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/AUn3o6RCE1c)